# alert box empty for php javascript

Tags: php, javascript

why does this script show empty alert box. I am trying to use php value in javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 alert(<?php echo count($myorder) ?>); </script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably because you are not encapsulating the PHP output into quotes (JavaScript should give you an error on that?), and the `echo` statement is missing a <strike>mandatory</strike> optional semicolon.

Try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 alert("<?php echo count($myorder); ?>"); </script>
```

Comment: both are correct (missing the ; in the echo, and no quotations around the alert, however it functions without issue in firefox and IE as is - so not 100% sure that's it.

Comment: A semi-colon is not required at the end of a `<?php ?>` block.

Comment: @Daniel you're right - I wasn't sure and didn't have the time to test. Corrected my answer, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

remove the javascript - and just echo the variable to the screen, what does the value show?

looking at the sample, even though as the previous answer mentioned you missed the ; at the end of the echo, and you didn't quote the alert, it still actually works at least in firefox and IE8.  The count should always return a value even on a null value or a non-array, so not 100% sure but would be interested to see what it shows in php only.

just for sanity sake try this....

```
<?php echo "before | " . count($myorder) . " | after";?>
```

and what is the output....

if the value is not an array, is null, or is an array with zero entries it should be

> before 0 after

and if it has elements it would be whatever the count is, obviously.